# Kubernetes/Rancher: NetworkPolicy with Traefik

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, rancher, kubernetes-networkpolicy

we are using Rancher to setup clusters with Canal as the CNI. We decided to use Traefik as an Ingress Controller and wanted to create a NetworkPolicy. We disabled ProjectIsolation and Traefik is running in the System project in the kube-system namespace.

I created this Policy:

```yaml
# deny all ingress traffic
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}

---
# allow traefik
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-allow-traefik
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
    - from:
      - namespaceSelector:
          matchLabels:
            namespace: kube-system
        podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: traefik

---
# allow backnet
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-allow-backnet
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
    - from:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 10.1.0.0/24
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 10.2.0.0/24
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 192.168.0.0/24
```

But somehow we can't get this to work. The connection gets time-outed and that's it. Is there a major problem with this policy? Something i didn't understand about NetworkPolicies?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try to add `policyTypes` `Ingress` into your yaml file as described in the example in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)?

Comment: @thomas I just added the `policyTypes` as you mentioned but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you enable CNI plugin? It has to be enabled to enforce the network policies. More info [here](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/security/hardening-2.4/).

Comment: Yeah, it was enabled by default while we created the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the Problem. It was a plain beginner mistake:

```yaml
- namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      namespace: kube-system
```

I didn't add the `Label` `namespace: kube-system` to the `Namespace` `kube-system`.

After adding the Label it worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this from K8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#targeting-a-namespace-by-its-name), There is now a label called `kubernetes.io/metadata.name` on all namespaces, which can be used to select a specific namespace as such:

```
- namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      kubernetes.io/metadata.name: kube-system
```